# Counter of numbers divisible by 2

Tags: python

What I am doing wrong? This is my Python code where I want to count all numbers divisible by 2 but the output is "1", not "5".

```
for x in range(10):
    x += 1
    count = 0
    if x % 2 == 0:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: You reset the `count` to 0 with each iteration... Put `count = 0` ***before*** the loop...

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `count` to 0 on every iteration. What you want to do is move that initialization out of the loop.

On a side note, you can change the range directly, rather than doing `x += 1`

```py
count = 0
for x in range(1, 11):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

If you wanted to be fancy, you could also use the fact that `bool` is actually `int` in python to make this into a one-liner

```py
print(sum(not (x % 2) for x in range(1,11)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting your variable count to 0 inside the loop.
You have to declare it out of it, like this

```
count = 0
for x in range(10):
   x += 1
   if x % 2 == 0:
      count += 1
 print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0

for x in range(10):
    if(x%2==0):
        count += 1
        print(x)
    
print(count)
```